# tkinter: How can I keep widgets in a Framed Canvas inside the Frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

While I'm working on a project, I like to code up quick tests at the Python prompt to figure out the details of how to do things I'm not familiar with.  Such is the case here.  I need a scrollable *portion* of a window, so after doing some reading, I decided the correct way would be to use a Canvas widget linked to a Scrollbar.  It took some trial-and-error as I've never used the Canvas widget before, but I figured it out... ish.

However, when I scroll the Canvas, the Framed widgets on it will overlap and obscure other parts of the interface, including the LabelFrame which is the Canvas' parent.  This is most undesirable.  I tried various combinations of using the `lower()` and `lift()` methods of the Canvas, the LabelFrame, and the Frame on the Canvas to remedy this, but none did.  I did find that by setting the `textwidget` option of the LabelFrame to a Label widget, and calling `lift()` on *that*, it will appear on top of the Canvas widgets; but they'll still obscure the LabelFrame's border and other widgets below the LabelFrame, so that doesn't help much.  Here's about what I did in my testing:

```
import tkinter
win = tkinter.Tk()

outerFrame = tkinter.LabelFrame(win, text="Outer Frame")
outerFrame.grid(sticky=tkinter.NSEW)

outerButton = tkinter.Button(win, text="Button")
outerButton.grid(padx=3, pady=1, sticky=tkinter.EW)

canvasScroll = tkinter.Scrollbar(outerFrame, orient=tkinter.VERTICAL)
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(outerFrame, yscrollcommand=canvasScroll.set, scrollregion=(0,0,0,512))
canvasScroll.configure(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tkinter.NSEW)
canvasScroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tkinter.NSEW)

innerFrame = tkinter.LabelFrame(win, text="Inner Frame")
innerLabel = tkinter.Label(innerFrame, text="Label 1")
innerCheckbutton1 = tkinter.Checkbutton(innerFrame, text="Checkbutton 1")
innerCheckbutton2 = tkinter.Checkbutton(innerFrame, text="Checkbutton 2")
innerListbox = tkinter.Listbox(innerFrame)
innerEntry = tkinter.Entry(innerFrame, width=10)
innerButton = tkinter.Button(innerFrame, text="Inner Button")
innerRadiobutton1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(innerFrame, text="Radiobutton 1")
innerRadiobutton2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(innerFrame, text="Radiobutton 2")

innerLabel.grid()
innerCheckbutton1.grid()
innerCheckbutton2.grid()
innerListbox.grid(sticky=tkinter.NSEW)
innerEntry.grid()
innerButton.grid()
innerRadiobutton1.grid()
innerRadiobutton2.grid()

canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor=tkinter.NW, window=innerFrame)
```

It demonstrates the issue pretty well.  What I want is a way to keep the Canvas widgets in the Canvas' LabelFrame.  Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Сhange `innerFrame = tkinter.LabelFrame(win, text="Inner Frame")` to `innerFrame = tkinter.LabelFrame(canvas, text="Inner Frame")`. Might work

Comment: Wow! Such a simple change, and it works perfectly!  Thank you so much!  I feel kinda stupid now, but I appreciate the help.  If you could post that as an answer rather than as a comment, I'd be happy to mark it as such. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a typical situation, when one widget is placed inside another (using `master` parameter), the parent clips it, and therefore the part of the child widget that is outside the parent is not visible. Other widgets will not perform clipping for this child, only its master does it.

So when you created `innerFrame` as `innerFrame = tkinter.LabelFrame(win, text="Inner Frame")`, you set `win` to be its master and so it is responsible for clipping. Since the canvas is not a master for `innerFrame`, it will not do any clipping and so widgets created with `create_window` function will extend beyond the canvas and be visible outside it.

So to make sure everything works as it should, set the `master` for the `innerFrame` to be `canvas` rather than `win`.

It can be shown that clipping still works in the following example:

```
import tkinter
win = tkinter.Tk()
win.configure(bg='green')
win.geometry('1200x600')
clipping_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(win, bg='purple', text='clipping frame')
clipping_frame.pack(pady=40)

outerFrame = tkinter.LabelFrame(clipping_frame, text="Outer Frame")
outerFrame.grid(padx=70, pady=70)

canvasScroll = tkinter.Scrollbar(outerFrame, orient=tkinter.VERTICAL)
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(outerFrame, yscrollcommand=canvasScroll.set, scrollregion=(0, -100, 0, 712))
canvasScroll.configure(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tkinter.NSEW)
canvasScroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tkinter.NSEW)

innerFrame = tkinter.LabelFrame(clipping_frame, text="Inner Frame")
innerLabel = tkinter.Label(innerFrame, text="Label 1")
innerListbox = tkinter.Listbox(innerFrame, height=30)

innerLabel.grid()
innerListbox.grid(sticky=tkinter.NSEW)

canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor=tkinter.NW, window=innerFrame)
win.mainloop()
```

You will notice that `innerFrame` is clipped by `clipping_frame`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: line 5, in <module>
    clipping_frame = tk.LabelFrame(win, bg='purple', text='clipping frame')
NameError: name 'tk' is not defined. Should be tkinter.LabelFrame

Comment: @toyotaSupra my bad, thanks for noticing. Fixed now

Comment: @DanyaK Once again, thanks!  I think what was throwing me originally was this line from the [Tkinter Reference handbook](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_window.html): _"The widget must be the child of the same top-level window as the canvas, or the child of some widget located in the same top-level window,"_ which sounds (to me) like you can't use the canvas as parent.  Ah well, now I know!